# I want to remove pages/ from my url in angular 5

Tags: angular

I have  `{ path: 'pages/:id', component: PagesComponent },`
that's why my URL is appearing like

http://localhost:4200/pages/aboutus

so, for SEO purposes I want to remove that pages work from URL to display URL like

http://localhost:4200/aboutus

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What issue are you having when you to remove the `pages` part?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what is the component associated with "aboutus" (if there is one).
Also I advise you to document the guide, it is very well structured.

https://angular.io/guide/router